# arctween and dataset change in donut chart with d3,js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

With the click of a button, I want to add a new dataset to my doughnut chart and have it transition the new dataset. The code I've written sort of does that but it runs into an issue when the number of individual data within the dataset is different from the previous i.e. going from [1,2] to [1,2,3,4].

I think the issue is that I need to create a new path whenever there the new dataset has more data, and remove paths whenever it has less. However, when I try to append data in my click function, it will append it without removing the old paths and will overlap on the chart.

Here is a version without appending, where the arctween will work but there will be empty pie arcs because I don't append path (arctween works half the time):
http://jsfiddle.net/njrPF/1/

```
var pieW = 500;
var pieH = 500;
var innerRadius = 100;
var outerRadius = 200;

var results_pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);
var pie_arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var svg_pie = d3.select("#pieTotal")
    .attr("width", pieW)
    .attr("height", pieH)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + pieW / 2 + "," + pieH / 2 + ")")
    .attr("class", "piechart");

var pie_path = svg_pie.selectAll("path").data(results_pie([1, 2]))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", pie_arc)
    .each(function (d) {
    this._current = d;
}) // store the initial values
.attr("class", "vote_arc")
    .attr("value", function (d, i) {
    return (i - 1);
});


var pie_votes = [1, 2];
var pie_colors = ["#0f0", "#f00"];
$(svg_pie).bind("monitor", worker);
$(svg_pie).trigger("monitor");

function worker(event) {
    pie_path = pie_path.data(results_pie(pie_votes))
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return pie_colors[i];
    });

    pie_path.transition().duration(500).attrTween("d", arcTween).each('end', function (d) {
        if (d.value <= 0) {
            this.remove();
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(svg_pie).trigger("monitor");
    }, 500);
}

function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function (t) {
        return pie_arc(i(t));
    };
}

$('button').click(function () {
    pie_votes = [];
    pie_colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); i++) {
        //sets new values on pie arcs
        pie_votes.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        pie_colors.push("#" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)).toString(16));
    }
    pie_path = pie_path.data(results_pie(pie_votes))
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return pie_colors[i]
    });

    pie_path.transition().duration(500).attrTween("d", arcTween).each('end', function (d) {
        if (d.value <= 0) {
            this.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a version where I try to append new paths but they overlap:
http://jsfiddle.net/njrPF/3/

```
var pieW = 500;
var pieH = 500;
var innerRadius = 100;
var outerRadius = 200;

var results_pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null);
var pie_arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var svg_pie = d3.select("#pieTotal")
    .attr("width", pieW)
    .attr("height", pieH)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + pieW / 2 + "," + pieH / 2 + ")")
    .attr("class", "piechart");

var pie_path = svg_pie.selectAll("path").data(results_pie([1, 2]))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", pie_arc)
    .each(function (d) {
    this._current = d;
}) // store the initial values
.attr("class", "vote_arc")
    .attr("value", function (d, i) {
    return (i - 1);
});

function arcTween(a) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
    this._current = i(0);
    return function (t) {
        return pie_arc(i(t));
    };
}

$('button').click(function () {
    pie_votes = [];
    pie_colors = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); i++) {
        //sets new values on pie arcs
        pie_votes.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
        pie_colors.push("#" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215)).toString(16));
    }
    pie_path = pie_path.data(results_pie(pie_votes))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", pie_arc)
        .each(function (d) {
        this._current = d; }) // store the initial values
    .attr("class", "vote_arc")
        .attr("value", function (d, i) {
        return (i - 1);
    });
    pie_path.attr("fill", function (d, i) {
        return pie_colors[i]
    });

    pie_path.transition().duration(500).attrTween("d", arcTween).each('end', function (d) {
        if (d.value <= 0) {
            this.remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the enter and exit selections as well as the update selection. See for example [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html). The relevant code in your case would be

```
pie_path = pie_path.data(results_pie(pie_votes));

pie_path.enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", pie_arc)
    .each(function (d) {
        this._current = d;
    }) // store the initial values
    .attr("class", "vote_arc")
        .attr("value", function (d, i) {
        return (i - 1);
    });

pie_path.exit().remove();
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/njrPF/4/).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do a callback after the remove()? Would it be something like remove(callback)?

Comment: What do you want to do in the callback? `.remove()` should be the last thing.

Comment: Basically I put the pie data change in a function and I pass in the data and the colors. I wanted it to animate in a way where if you're pushing in a completely new set of data (different length in the data array), it will handle it by first setting everything to 0 (so it'll be like the arctween is 'emptying'), removing the data, initializing the new set of data, and then animating the new data. So this would basically take 4 calls of an altered version of the code above to manipulate the movement of the pie chart.

Comment: You can set a `.delay()` for each transition, which should allow you to do what you want. You can simply delay the start of the enter transition until the exit transition has finished.

Comment: Does the .delay() occur relative to framerate? Seems like it's just after a specific amount of time so slower systems might act weird?

Comment: It's in milliseconds, same as `.duration()`. It's accurate in my experience.